# How to define a subarray efficiently?

Tags: idl-programming-language

I am getting the error

```
Unable to allocate memory: to make array
```

when I try the following:

```
; A is an array
ind = WHERE(A GE 1)
A = A[ind]
```

Was wondering what I can do to free up memory?
I tried

`A = temporary(A)[ind]`

but that gives me a syntax error.

Comment: Can you provide more details on `A` (size, datatype)? In principle, this error could mean that you need to rewrite parts of your code so that it is more memory-efficient; the line that causes the exception might just be that one operation too much...

Comment: Which line gives you the error?